# Where can i find nutch.war file?

Tags: eclipse, solr, nutch

Q-1) I tried building 'build.xml' from nutch folder by running it in eclipse ant, but to my bad luck,i couldnt find nutch.war anywhere in my workplace.
It aint available inside the unzipped nutch-bin also.
Where can i find nutch.war file??

Q-2) I read somewhere that its better to crawl from Nutch and search via Solr. So, I integrated Solr within Nutch. Would that mean I would see a new replacement searching UI for Solr instead of Nutch searching UI or would it be same as Nutch UI ??

 I mean this Nutch UI [1]: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=nutch&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=29yBPvjJbGXPTM:&imgrefurl=http://www.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/16/introduction-to-nutch-2.html&docid=69xYu60x353AyM&imgurl=http://today.java.net/images/2006/02/nutch-figure-2-1.gif&w=500&h=325&ei=B0D6T8bgA5GrrAeO_Z3eBg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=687&vpy=192&dur=2329&hovh=181&hovw=279&tx=149&ty=100&sig=101777148678843861437&page=1&tbnh=121&tbnw=186&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:3,s:0,i:96

Comment: As far as I know nutch is not a web application. Why do you expect a war file?

Comment: It is.<br>
I want to run a user efficient search engine from its UI not from any terminal-cygwin or kernel.

Comment: Fine. Solr is a search engine, and a web application. Nutch isn't a search engine and isn't a web application. You can configure nutch to index data within a running Solr.

Comment: Ok!!!
Can you tell me how can i search from Solr UI. I dont want to search using commands on the terminal.
<br>
For Eg:- If i type in any query in the query bar, it should give back the result's page accordingly.

Comment: Kind of similar to this link...
<br> http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=nutch&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=29yBPvjJbGXPTM:&imgrefurl=http://www.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/16/introduction-to-nutch-2.html&docid=69xYu60x353AyM&imgurl=http://today.java.net/images/2006/02/nutch-figure-2-1.gif&w=500&h=325&ei=B0D6T8bgA5GrrAeO_Z3eBg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=687&vpy=192&dur=2329&hovh=181&hovw=279&tx=149&ty=100&sig=101777148678843861437&page=1&tbnh=121&tbnw=186&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:3,s:0,i:96

Comment: You know, if you'd bother to read what you wrote, you'd notice that <br> doesn't do anything in stackoverflow comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build nutch from the command line, and it doesn't build a war file, it builds a jar file called nutch-n.n.job

Oh, on further investigation (ie. 10 seconds with Google) I discovered that you build a war file with the command "ant war".  It's a pity you didn't think to type "nutch installation" into Google instead of repeatedly complaining how nobody answered your question.

http://www.nutchinstall.blogspot.ca/
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.<br>Mee too gets a .jar file but i guess that does not do any good because what i want is the Nutch search UI which is only possible if I have .war file. <br> The .war goes into the tomcat webapps directory through which i can get Nutch search UI.

Comment: Whats the importance of .jar file...<br> Mind sharing your thoughts??

Comment: The web ui appears to be there in the .jar file.  It is possible to load a .jar file into Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Is it uploaded via the "localhost:8080/manager/html" page???<br> If yes, then i am not able to access the manager page.

Comment: and if it is done by directly copying it in webapps folder, then it does not generate a directory for the same upon starting the tomcat.

Comment: I also tried "# ant war" command in the terminal to build a .war file....but still it was not created.